# Reactjs changing states from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my main `Duck` component I have a state `power: off`. I would like to be able to switch the `power` to `on` by clicking on the visible `off` string, which is wrapped in a component `Lucas` inside my main.

In the `/**/` tags are where I would like to modify the prop, and subsequently the state of `power`. I understand that the code below is not supposed to work. But it hopefully gives a clear idea of what exactly I'm trying to accomplish.

```
var Lucas = React.createClass({

/*
controller:function(){
    this.setProps({power: 'on'});
},
*/

render: function(){
    return (<div><p onClick={this.controller}>{this.props.power}</p></div>);
    }
});

var Duck = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
    return {power: 'off'}
},

render:function(){
    return (<div>
    <Lucas power={this.state.power}/>
    </div>);
    }
});
```

Included on JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mfsc3mkx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a method in `Lucas` to change its `state`, in this case the `power` value, and pass it to `Lucas`.

Something like this

```
var Lucas = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
      return (<div><p onClick={this.props.turnOn}>{this.props.power}</p></div>);
      }
});

var Duck = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {power: 'off'}
    },
    turnOn: function(){
        this.setState({power : 'on'})
    },
    render:function(){
        return (<div>
             <Lucas power={this.state.power} turnOn={this.turnOn}/>
          </div>);
    }
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/51954/)

Answer (score 1):

In your `Lucas` component, you should set `onClick` prop:

```
var Lucas = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.power);
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div><p onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.power}</p></div>
    );
  }
});
```

Next, in your `Duck` component, you need to define `onLucasClick` callback, and provide it to `Lucas` `onClick` prop:

```
var Duck = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function() {
    return {
      power: 'off'
    };
  },

  handleLucasClick(power) {
    this.setState({
      power: power === 'on' ? 'off' : 'on'
    });
  }

  render:function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Lucas power={this.state.power} onClick={this.handleLucasClick.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```